# scrapy Request callback does not get fired

Tags: python, request, scrapy

I am totally lost here. I am implementing a scrapy project where the item consists of values on different pages. This is what I have:

```
self.logger.debug("Bilanz URL %s", item['bilanz_url'])
return Request(url=item['bilanz_url'], 
    callback=self.parse_estimations, 
    errback=self.error_handler, 
    dont_filter=True,
    meta = {'item': dict(item)})

def parse_estimations(self, response):
    self.logger.info("Function parse_estimations %s", response.url)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['raw_estimations'] = response.xpath("//td[starts-with(text(), 'KGV')]/ancestor::table").extract_first()
    yield item
```

Problem now is that the function `parse_estimations` is never reached, nor does the errback handler get called. I could as well `yield` it with the same effect.
Am I missing something obvious here?

Additional info: these extensions and middlewares are enabled:

```
[scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
[scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
```

Comment: Do you see the duplicate request filtered error records?

Comment: @alecxe: Thanks for looking into this. Admittedly, I do see them, but only for the first item page (the one where this code is in the response function).

Comment: What if you set the `dont_filter=True` when returning/yielding the `Request`?

Comment: @alecxe: Nothing, really. I have edited my question and included the function `parse_estimations` - the logging text never appears nor does the expected item.

Comment: @alecxe: Additional info: when I use the command `scrapy parse` with the function directly, the Request gets fired and the corresponding function is reached - very strange for me.

Comment: @alecxe: Ok, something learned with `scrapy` - requests seem not to get fired immediately. I have cut down my initial pages to three and tada - the callback was reached. Guess, I have to become somewhat more patient :) Thanks for your help anyways.